# setting the thread's name when Thread object is created?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. Can anyone explain what happens in the main method??

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        //setting a name using the constructor
        Thread t=new Thread("main"){
            //what is this? a static block?? need an explanation to this.
            {setName("DemoThread");} 
        };
        //output is DemoThread. Since it set the name again.
        System.out.println(t.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This line:

```
{setName("DemoThread");}
```

is called an *initializer block* (or *instance initializer block*). It looks like a static initializer block, but without the `static` keyword. It's useful for anonymous classes because they can't have named constructors. More details can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread t = new Thread("main") {
    {
        setName("DemoThread");
    } 
};
```

The above is an anonymous inner class being created. The `{}` is an instance initializer block in Java. It would be a static block if it had `static { }`.

Basically you can invoke any operations from the instance initializer block that belongs to the instance (`this`) reference.

In this case, it's calling `setName` on the current instance of `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

The code is creating an anonymous Thread subclass with

```
new Thread("main") {

};
```

In this anonymous class, there is an initialization block:

```
{setName("DemoThread");}
```